# Determining if a spherical triangle is visible

Tags: visibility, projection

I have a sphere formed of spherical triangles. Each triangle is determined by 3 normalized vectors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrY96.png

I need to determine wich triangles (spherical projcetions) I can see if I know: camera position, view normal vector and fov 45.0 deg. The problem is if the camera is very close to the sphere, the  spherical projection of a triangle may be visible and its flat version may not and vice versa.

Here is an example:
[side view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcbXV.png)

Comment: You might need the center point or some other characteristic of the tirangle to calculate the sphere beneath it.

Comment: I don't quite catch you. I can calculate center points... it may be in the view area and may not, but the triangle may still be visible.

Comment: Well at one point or another, you will have to calculate if your viewing angle intersects with the part of the sphere that is discribed by your triangle.

Comment: So, first of all I need to find the closest point on the flat triangle to the view vector?

Comment: http://rghost.ru/8xYPCsM9C/image.png , In this example I need to determane if the orange area is visible. Because of the view vector, in this case the closest point on the edge of the flat triangle is outside the view area, and the spherical projection too: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JcbXV.png